# os.Read() How is work? Golang

Tags: go, go-packages

Why if I print `bs`, before calling `Read()`, it prints nothing, but after the call `file.Read(bs)`, it shows the inside of test.txt file. Unless `bs` is only argument, how `Read()` can Change it?

```
package main
import (
"os"
"fmt"
)

func main() {
    file , err := os.Open("test.txt")
if err == nil {
} else {

}
stat , _ := file.Stat()


bs := make([]byte, stat.Size())
fmt.Println(string(bs))
bsf ,err := file.Read(bs)

if err != nil{
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(bsf)
}
fmt.Println(string(bs))


}
```

Output:

```
(Line1)                                           
(Line2)hi, This is Example text in test.txt file.
```

Comment: [Read](https://godoc.org/os#File.Read) reads bytes from the file. The buffer starts of empty and is filled by the call to Read.

Comment: Take the Tour of Go to learn about all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unless bs is only argument, how Read() can Change it?

It seems that you may be missing basic knowledge about programming languages in general. There are different kind of "values". There are pointers (or references) and there are the "usual values".

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func changeIt(p *int) {
    *p = 9
}

func main() {
    a := 1
    fmt.Println(a)
    changeIt(&a)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

It'll print `1 9` not `1 1`. `*int` is not an integer, but a pointer to an integer. A pointer is a value that points (references) another value. If you have a value of type pointer you get the actual value that the pointer points to by using `*` (which is called dereferencing):

```
func main() {
    a := 1
    b := &a
    fmt.Println(b, *b)
}
```

`b` is a pointer (of type `*int`) that points to `a`. The `println` will print the location of `a` followed by the value of `a` which is usually something like uhm `0x10414020 1`. We can also modify the value a pointer points to by using `*p = ...`:

```
func main() {
    a := 1
    b := &a
    *b = 9
    fmt.Println(b, *b, a)
}
```

which will print `0x10414020 9 9`.

Now, `[]byte` is a slice... slices are like pointers. When you do

```
func changeIt(buf []byte) {
    buf[0] = 10
}

func main() {
    data := []byte{1,2,3}
    changeIt(data)
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

You're not actually passing the values `[1 2 3]` to `changeIt` but a pointer to those values. Thus here the `println` will show `[10 2 3]`. Compare this to:

```
func changeIt(buf [3]byte) {
    buf[0] = 10
}

func main() {
    data := [3]byte{1,2,3}
    changeIt(data)
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

Which will print `[1 2 3]` and it will pass the values `[1 2 3]` and not a pointer so changeIt essentially works on a copy and the `buf[0] = 10` has no effect. Remember: `[n]T` is an array, `[]T` is a slice. `[n]T` is a "raw value" and `[]T` is a "pointer value".